# Can a Swift enum have a function/closure as a raw value?

Tags: swift, enums, closures, enumeration

I know an enum can have a closure as an *associated* value, such as:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case closureOne (String, Double -> Double)
    case closureTwo (String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
}
```

But, can an enum have a closure as a *raw* value? For instance, does something like this work?

```
enum someEnum: () -> Void {
    case closureOne = doSomething
    case closureTwo  = doSomethingElse
}
```

where

```
let doSomething = {
    // Do something here.
}

let doSomethingElse {
    // Do something else here.
}
```

Comment: Note that having a closure as a raw value (e.g. `enum someEnum: (Int) -> Void`) is not the same as having _a result of function execution_ (void in your case) as a raw value (e.g. `case closureOne = doSomething(num: 1)`). The later could be expressed by `enum someEnum: Void`, while earlier would need to have values like `case closureOne = doSomething` (no argument values)

Comment: @KirilS. Yes you are correct. I have edited the question so the enum raw values are closures instead of results of functions. So would this type of thing be possible? I still get various errors with this.

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149): "Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types." Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Well I'm working with a UITableView and reusable cells, and I want to be able to run various IU-related tasks based on the state of certain variables. So I'm trying to find the most efficient way to run a function given the state of a variable. Any suggestions? As of now I'm putting these tasks in the `didSet` of the variable, but it's getting tedious. There's a lot of IBOutlets to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as straight forward, but you could use `OptionSet`, see [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable):

> Unlike enumerations, option sets provide a nonfailable init(rawValue:) initializer to convert from a raw value, because option sets don’t have an enumerated list of all possible cases. Option set values have a one-to-one correspondence with their associated raw values.

Could be something like this:

```
func doSomething() {}
func doSomethingElse() {}

struct MyClosures: OptionSet {

    static let closureOne = MyClosures(rawValue: doSomething)
    static let closureTwo = MyClosures(rawValue: doSomethingElse)

    let rawValue: () -> Void

    init(rawValue: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    init() {
        rawValue = {}
    }

    mutating func formUnion(_ other: __owned MyClosures) {
        // whatever makes sense for your case
    }

    mutating func formIntersection(_ other: MyClosures) {
        // whatever makes sense for your case
    }

    mutating func formSymmetricDifference(_ other: __owned MyClosures) {
        // whatever makes sense for your case
    }

    static func == (lhs: MyClosures, rhs: MyClosures) -> Bool {
        // whatever makes sense for your case
        return false
    }
}
```

And so you can use it as:

```
let myClosures: MyClosures = [ .closureOne, .closureTwo ]
```

HOWEVER looking at your explanation in the comment:

> So I'm trying to find the most efficient way to run a function given the state of a variable.

I think what you actually want is some sort of state machine. Some examples are available [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-machine-in-swift-8687673f5df6) and [here](https://medium.com/eggs-design/building-a-state-driven-app-in-swiftui-using-state-machines-32379ca37283)